# VBA - find second occurrence of substring "TL" and delete everything after

Tags: excel, vba, split, substring

**What it does:** I have a section of code which finds a substring TL in a cell, and forces the numbers following it to be of length 6 by adding or deleting 0s immediately following "TL-". (ie `TL-00072 -> TL-000072`, `TL-034 -> TL-000034`, `TL-000000789 -> TL-000789`)

**What I want it to do:** However, sometimes there are multiple TL values in one cell. I need to find if there is a second occurance of TL, and, if yes, delete that second occurance and everything following it.

Example:

```
Start:                           Output:
TL-000789 TL-000187 TL-000773  ->   TL-000789
TL-000689 TL -000787           ->   TL-000689
TL-000982 TL - 980819          ->   TL-000982
```

---

This is the attempt at code I have been working on (incorrect and not working) using split (maybe trim would work too?) that would find the second occurence of TL and delete everything after it. Full working code below that.

**CURRENT ATTEMPT AT CODE**

```
Dim splitValues As Variant
        If Str(str, "TL" + 1) 'do not know how to get SECOND occurrence
            splitValues = Split(theValue, "TL")
            theValue = splitValues(0)
        End If
```

**WORKING CODE**

[will add new code to beginning] (explanation at top of question)

NOTE: StartSht is the workbook where the values are as well as the code.
      All values being altered are in column "C"

```
'force length of TL/CT to be 6/4 numbers long, eliminate spaces
    Dim str As String, ret As String, tmp As String, j As Integer, k As Integer
    For k = 2 To StartSht.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
        ret = ""
        str = StartSht.Range("C" & k).Value
        'for TL numbers

 ''''''''''''''new code goes here''''''''''''''''''

        If InStr(str, "TL") > 0 Then
            For j = 1 To Len(str)
                tmp = Mid(str, j, 1)
                If IsNumeric(tmp) Then ret = ret + tmp
            Next j
            'force to 6 numbers if too short; add 0s immediately after "TL-"
            For j = Len(ret) + 1 To 6
                ret = "0" & ret
            Next j
            'force to 6 numbers if too long; eliminate 0s immediately after "TL-"
            If Len(ret) > 6 Then
                Debug.Print Len(ret)
                For j = Len(ret) To 7 Step -1
                If Mid(ret, 1, 1) = "0" Then
                    ret = Right(ret, j - 1)
                End If
                Next j
            End If
            'eliminate superfluous spaces around "TL-"
            ret = "TL-" & ret
            StartSht.Range("C" & k).Value = ret
        'for CT numbers
        ElseIf InStr(str, "CT") > 0 Then
            For j = 1 To Len(str)
                tmp = Mid(str, j, 1)
                If IsNumeric(tmp) Then ret = ret + tmp
            Next j
        'force to 4 numbers if too short; add 0s immediately after "CT-"
        For j = Len(ret) + 1 To 4
            ret = "0" & ret
        Next j
        'force to 4 numbers if too long; eliminate 0s immediately after "CT-"
        If Len(ret) > 4 Then
            Debug.Print Len(ret)
            For j = Len(ret) To 5 Step -1
            If Mid(ret, 1, 1) = "0" Then
                ret = Right(ret, j - 1)
        End If
        Next j
    End If
    'eliminate superfluous spaces around "CT-"
    ret = "CT-" & ret
    StartSht.Range("C" & k).Value = ret
 End If
Next k
```

Comment: Can't you just use For example: `strKeepLeft=LEFT(TextToSearch,Mid(TextToSearch,"TL",3)-1)`  Mid finds occurrence of a string in a string so we tell it to start at position 3 (assuming first TL occurrence is always in 1,2 position)... on error, we take the whole TextToSearch string as there is no 2nd TL statement.

Comment: Looks like it makes sense but I am unsure how to implement it. I tried using `set` and your code but then am unsure how I would reference it later ... I am new to VBA so I am still unsure of how to call everything @xQbert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could just redefine str if you find a second "TL".  After the line:
`If InStr(str, "TL") > 0 Then`
add another IF statement:
`If InStr(3, str, "TL") > 0 Then str = Mid(str, 1, Instr(3, str, "TL") - 2)`

Then continue with the rest of your code using the new `str`.

Comment: wow beautiful! Thank you @tmh8885 . If you have a second to explain, what do the 3 and the -1 do to make it eliminate those values?

Comment: Sure.  When looking for string "TL" in `str`, we want to start at 3 to avoid the first instance.  As far as the -1, I edited it to change to -2 instead, it was an oversight on my part.  What it's doing is finding that second instance of "TL" and excluding it from `str`.  But we want to exclude more than just from "TL" on, we also want to exclude the space, giving us a trimmed `str`.